# Opencv error - Imread statement in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I compiled this code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2   as cv
simps = np.zeros((8000,128,128,3))
j = 0
for i in range(1000,9001):

        print(j)

        if   (i % 10 == i and i != 10):
            filename = '/content/cropped/' + str(i) + '.png'
        elif (i % 100 == i and i != 100):
            filename = '/content/cropped/' + str(i) + '.png'
        elif (i % 1000 == i and i != 1000):
            filename = '/content/cropped/' + str(i) + '.png'
        elif (i % 10000 == i and i != 10000):
            filename = '/content/cropped/' + str(i) + '.png'
        print(filename)
        print(type(filename))
        simps[j,:,:,:] = cv.imread(filename)
        print(simps[j,:,:,:])
        simps[j,:,:,:] = cv.resize(simps[j,:,:,:],(128,128));
        j += 1
simps = simps.astype('uint8')
np.save('/content/simps.npy',simps)
```

but get this error :

```
     17         print(filename)
     18         print(type(filename))
---> 19         simps[j,:,:,:] = cv.imread(filename)
     20         print(simps[j,:,:,:])
     21         simps[j,:,:,:] = cv.resize(simps[j,:,:,:],(128,128));

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,200,3) into shape (128,128,3)
```

this error is on `cv.imread()` but my code is correct . my code compiled on colab but when i compile on my system this worked. do you know that error?

Comment: If answer helped,don't forget to accept it by checking the mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fill the array before resizing it, try on line 19

```
simps[j,:,:,:] = cv.resize(cv.imread(filename),(128,128))
```

Comment: if this doesn't work you might have to use an intermediate array, current = cv.imread(filename) then current = cv.resize(current,(128,128) then simps[j,:,:,:] = current